# DataTextField combination from 2 columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple model class User *(Data annotations removed for simplicity)*:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public int Nr { get; set; }
```

And model Registration *(again, data annotations removed for simplicity)*:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
public User User { get; set; }
public DateTime BookTaken { get; set; }
public DateTime BookReturned { get; set; }
```

The Registration model uses UserId, therefor i created a select inside my form in cshtml file:

```
<select asp-for="@Model.registration.UserId" asp-items="@Model.UsersOptions"></select>
```

The @Model comes from my ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<Registration> registrations { get; set; }
public Registration registration { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<User> users { get; set; }
public SelectList UsersOptions { get; set; }
```

And the viewModel is being passed from the Controllers Method:

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? Id)
    {
        RegistrationsIndexViewModel viewModel = new RegistrationsIndexViewModel()
        {
            registrations = _registrationRepository.GetAllRegistrations(),
            registration = _registrationRepository.GetRegistration(Id ?? 0),
            users = _userRepository.GetAllUsers(),
            UsersOptions = new SelectList(_userRepository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Name"),
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**ALL** of this *(including the repositories that the code i did not show, since its not relevant to the question)* works fine. **BUT** `UsersOptions = new SelectList(_userRepository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Name"),` Makes the Html select list that only contains Name values. I want it to contain Name AND Lastname values from my User model.

If i use `new SelectList(_userRepository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Name")` OR `new SelectList(_userRepository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Lastname")` - works fine.
But when i try to combine both variables together `new SelectList(_userRepository.GetAllUsers(), "Id", "Name" + "Lastname")` - I get an error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**I DO** understand why. Its because it tried to find a column "NameLastname" instead of "Name" and "Lastname" separate. 
But **HOW** do i make it so in html my select list would contain both variable values *(name and lastname)* instead of just one of them.

is there away without using foreach loop inside cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to contain Name AND Lastname values from my User model.

You can do as follows:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? Id)
{

    var users = _userRepository.GetAllUsers();

    var usersForSelectList = users.Select(u => new 
    {
       Id = u.Id,
       DisplayName = u.Name + " " + u.LastName
    }).ToList();

    RegistrationsIndexViewModel viewModel = new RegistrationsIndexViewModel()
    {
        registrations = _registrationRepository.GetAllRegistrations(),
        registration = _registrationRepository.GetRegistration(Id ?? 0),

        UsersOptions = new SelectList(usersForSelectList , "Id", "DisplayName"),
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
It worked perfectly!

Now i feel dumb for not being able to figure it out on my own after spending more then 4 hours on it :D

Comment: @Lith Great to hear that. Happy coding.